# Звёздный рейтинг показывается для товаров, которые никто не оценивал

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Получается такая ситуация.

Звёздный рейтинг отображается практически на всех товарах, хотя никто не оставлял отзывов и не делал оценок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом возможно сбросить/обнулить рейтинг, чтобы звёзды исчезли для товаров, которые никто не оценивал?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите от куда и как выводится "звезды/рейтинг" например на страницах:

- **archive-product.php**
- **content-single-product.php**
- **content-product.php**

возможно код вставлен для красоты как HTML и его нужно будет просто удалить.

Так же посмотрите возможности и настройки темы, почитайте документацию к теме(если есть).

Если же рейтинг выводится из таблице БД, можете обнулить данные через SQL запрос:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET meta_value='0'
     WHERE meta_value > 0 and meta_key = '_wc_average_rating';

UPDATE `wp_commentmeta` SET meta_value='0'
     WHERE meta_value > 0 and meta_key='rating'
```

Или же можете попробовать плагин [YITH WooCommerce Advanced Reviews](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-advanced-reviews/)

Comment: Добавлю оговорку, что надо сделать проверку до обновления.

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверены, что скрипты правильно отображают рейтинг? Проверьте вывод скрипта для тех товаров, в которых сомневаетесь. Посмотрите базу данных, какие записи есть в ней по этому товару.

Вполне возможно, что это ошибка на уровне скрипта. Например, когда формула расчета рейтинга дает неверную оценку при отсутствии данных.